# Search Functionality for Stack Exchange versus Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, search

How come, when I search for something with StackExchange, the results are horrid.  But when I search on StackOverflow, the results are brilliant?  I posed this question to @codinghorror on Twitter and he said to post the question here with screenshots, so I am.  Here's the first 
step:

[image]

and here's the second step:

[image]

but StackOverflow's searching is magnificent.  Why not use that?

Comment: There's a Google in those results you're peeking

Answer (score 3):

When you search on stackexchange.com, you are searching *every Stack Exchange Site* -- that is, every site in this list, for the query term "regular expression":

https://stackexchange.com/sites

If you want to scope your search to *an individual site*, go to that site and use the search box at the upper right. Or enter the URL in this form:

`http://example.stackexchange.com/search?q=foo`

Where `example.stackexchange.com` is the site you want to search, and `foo` is the thing you want to find on that site.

Comment: Thanks.  I get it now.  Maybe, and I know this would be difficult, some rudimentary searching across sites could be done?  Then I could sort by date, for example?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the results differ is because StackExchange is a Google search, whereas when you search on Stackoverflow you get the results via SEs super secret search function, I mean not even Jon Skeet knows how this works(kidding, Jon Skeet wrote it... while sleeping). Plus everyone knows that QandA makes *everything* better.